# No descarga el archivo en el explorador usando OutputStream.Write en ASP.NET WebService C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webservice

Necesito descargar un archivo localizado en la carpeta App_Data de mi proyecto, todos los permisos están otorgados, tengo el siguiente codigo para descargar un archivo .xlsx llamando a un WebService en C#, el resultado del proceso no arroja error, pero no descarga el archivo en el explorador y en el preview al inspeccionar el proceso muestra caracteres desconocidos.

Codigo AJAX Jquery:

```
function DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../WebServices/getJSON.asmx/DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES',
        contentType: 'application/x-msexcel',
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
    });

    function OnSuccess() {
        console.log("donloading-services");
    }

}
```

Codigo del WebService C#:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES()
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data//");
        string filename = "SERVICES.xlsx";
        System.Web.HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        byte[] Content = File.ReadAllBytes(path + "SERVICES.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.OutputStream.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length);
        Response.Flush();
}
```

Output del Proceso inspeccionando en Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicionalmente si uso `Response.End()` en lugar de `Response.flush()` simplemente marca "Proces was being aborted", aunque use una estructura try-catch obtengo el mismo resultado, no suelta el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completando con la respuesta de **Gustavo Cantero** mi codigo Javascript queda asi:

```
function DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES() {
    window.location.href = '../WebServices/getJSON.asmx/DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES';
}
```

y finalmente buscando problemas parecidos, para que funcione la petición al WebService directamente hay que añadir las siguientes etiquetas al archivo `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Mi Web Service se queda sin editar; se soluciono en mi caso, Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás haciendo un post de AJAX, por lo cual, el archivo es enviado al stream que recibe tu request de $.ajax.

O sea, para que puedas descargarlo deberías hacer un link que vaya directamente al servicio web, o desde JavaScript podrías hacerlo así:

```
function DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES() {
    window.location = '../WebServices/getJSON.asmx/DOWNLOAD_EXCEL_SERVICES';
}
```

Espero te sirva.

¡Suerte!